# Asymmetric unique pair algorithm

Tags: algorithm, encryption, public-key-encryption, private-key, encryption-asymmetric

This is a fast question. I know about asymmetric encryption and I know that you can use the private key to decrypt whatever is encrypted with the public key. I know too that having the Private key I can generate the public one associated to it.

Here is my question: Is there any crypto algorithm to generate a pair of keys so I can't generate the public one having the private?

I would like to know if there is something like

Private(ciphertext) = Encrypted

Public(Encrypted) = ciphertext

Public(ciphertext) = Encrypted2

Private(Encrypted2)= ciphertext

And without generating the public from the private.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The RSA algorithm relies on the difficulty of factoring the product of two prime numbers. 
Two large, arbitrary, prime numbers `p` and `q` are used generate each private-public key pair. Given either only the private key or the public key, it is computationally difficult to find the other key without the prime numbers `p` and `q`. However, we do not `p` and `q` in order to apply either the public or the private key to a text.

Answer (score 0):

You can't conclude that because you have a private key then you can generate the public key. Take **RSA** as an example - here you can't deduct one of the keys in a key pair from the other - and which one is picked as the private key, and which is picked as the public key is random.

However, when storing the keys the private key file usually includes a copy of the public key as well (or enough information to recreate it).